# flask_admin db model not showing when logged in as admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, flask-security

I am trying to create an authentication function to my `Flask` webapp. I did some research and ended up using `flask_admin` integrated with `flask_security`. My app worked just fine after I added rolebased authentication but few minutes later I can not view the database when logged in as admin. I have no idea what went wrong a I did check my code but did not find anything wrong. Here is my code:

`__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore

 ...

admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap4')

from webapp import routes
from webapp import admin
from .models import *

user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)
```

`models.py` file:

```
from webapp import db, bcrypt, login_manager
from sqlalchemy import event
from flask_security import RoleMixin, UserMixin


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id)) 

roles_users_table = db.Table('roles_users',
  db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
  db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users_table, backref='user', lazy=True)

    @property
    def hashed_password(self):
        return self.password

    @hashed_password.setter
    def hashed_password(self, plain_text_password):
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plain_text_password).decode('utf-8')

    def check_password_correction(self, attempted_password):
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password, attempted_password)

@event.listens_for(User.password, 'set', retval=True)
def hash_user_password(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    if value != oldvalue:
        return bcrypt.generate_password_hash(value).decode('utf-8')
    return value

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
  description = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

`admin.py` file:

```
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email
from webapp import db, admin, user_datastore
from flask import redirect, url_for, request
from webapp.models import User, Role
from flask_security import current_user
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class AdminView(ModelView):
    column_searchable_list = ['username', 'email']
    column_editable_list = ['username', 'email']
    create_modal = True
    edit_modal = True

    form_args = {
        'username': {
        'validators': [DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=20)]
        },
        'email': {
        'validators': [DataRequired(), Email()]
        },
        'password': {
        'validators': [DataRequired(), Length(min=3)]
        }
    }

    def is_accessible(self): #This method do not get called
        print( "here")  
        return True

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs): #this also is not called
        print( "there")
        return redirect(url_for('login_page'))

        
admin.add_view(AdminView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(AdminView(Role, db.session))
```

This is how my page looks like:
[image: admin page]

What went wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your views to this:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
```

then

```
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Role, db.session))
```